# R quantstrat: Note: no visible binding for '<<-' assignment to '.strategy'

Tags: r, quantstrat

I installed R package quantstrat and its depencies as in the following code, as answered in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602829/installing-blotter-and-quantstrat-on-github):

```
install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)
install_github("braverock/FinancialInstrument")
install_github("joshuaulrich/xts")
install_github("braverock/blotter")
install_github("braverock/quantstrat")
install_github("braverock/PerformanceAnalytics")
```

When installing quantstrat package, I got the following output:

```
Note: no visible binding for '<<-' assignment to '.strategy' 
Note: no visible binding for '<<-' assignment to 'hold'
```

I do not know actually what it means. However, it seems I am not being able to make any transactions.

if I run `demo('bbands', ask=FALSE)`

I get the following output:

`Error in chart.Posn(Portfolio = "bbands", Symbol = stock.str) : 
  no transactions/positions to chart`

Session info:
 version  R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu
 ui       RStudio (1.1.453)
 language (EN)
 collate  en_US.UTF-8
 tz       America/Cuiaba
 date     2018-06-27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well answered by @FXQuantTrader, I could ignore the notes. It was a problem with version 0.14.5 where the notes are not relevant. It is fixed in version 0.14.6 and works perfectly now.

source: https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat/issues/88

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore the Notes on compiling (I get them too).  They won't affect the code adversely in any meaningful way.

Your error:

> Error in chart.Posn(Portfolio = "bbands", Symbol = stock.str) : 
>     no transactions/positions to chart

Comes about because you have no transactions done in your backtest.  So there are no positions to plot.  If you had transactions, you wouldn't get this error.

Make sure that `startDate` is a value that is before the start of your market data.  Otherwise `addPosLimit` may not work as intended and trades don't get generated. (Also, maybe also set your timezone to "UTC" if working with data with `Date` time indexes).  The demo works for me and generates trades.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I am not only in demo but also in my own code. Please, take a look at this question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072873/r-quantstrat-no-transactions-done-despite-all-the-signals